# Как узнать существует ли таблица в SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

У нас 2 разные версии в эксплуатации - 2012 и 2014, планируется миграция на 2016. Также меня еще интересуют временные таблицы, которые с решеткой.

Comment: Например так: select * from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] where TABLE_NAME = 'Clients' Временные таблицы существуют только в контексте выполнения.

Comment: Ещё неплохо во WHERE проверять и TABLE_SCHEMA - а то можно найти таблицу в другой БД...

Comment: @Akina, в другой БД - нельзя, INFORMATION_SCHEMA содержит объекты только текущей БД, а вот в другой схеме - да, можно, поэтому схему надо проверять.

Comment: @minamoto Да, сорри, невнимательно посмотрел, о каком сервере речь...

Comment: @Konst Спасибо, я так понимаю это для текущей ДБ, а существует способ для всех БД на сервере проверить?

Comment: @AleksandrTitenko, общего представления нет, но можно воспользоваться недокументированной функцией sp_MSforeachdb

Answer (score 2):

Мы обычно используем получение object_id таблицы (это и для всех остальных объектов подходит - функций, ХП, представлений и т.д.). Если он null - то объект не существует. Указание типа не обязательно, но желательно - т.к. может существовать объект другого типа с таким же именем.

```
if object_id('dbo.myImportantTable', 'U') is null ...
```

Соответственно, временные таблицы живут в tempdb, поэтому искать их надо там:

```
select object_id('tempdb.dbo.#testtable', 'U')
```